# Expression parser for unary operator

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I was trying to make an expression parser for two operators out of which only `^` is postfix unary, so with an operand it would look like `R^`.

The problem is that whenever the operator `^` is encountered somewhere other than the end, it just stops there and returns whatever parsed successfully. It means `"R;S;T^"` parses successfully, but `"R^;S;T^"` stops at `R`. However, `"(R^);S;T^"` just works fine.

I took help from an online post which he used for unary minus but that is a prefix operator (for example `-X`). His original solution was giving errors at `reservedOp2`, so I modified it to `reservedOp2 name = try (string name >> notFollowedBy (oneOf opChar))` and it produces the output mentioned above. I need it to work with or without parenthesis.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (many,optinal,(<|>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.Language (haskell)
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)

data RT = Comp RT RT        
        | Conv RT           
        | Var String
        deriving (Show)

whiteSpace = P.whiteSpace haskell
word = P.identifier haskell
parens = P.parens haskell
opChar = "^;"

reservedOp2 :: String -> CharParser st ()
reservedOp2 name = try (string name >> notFollowedBy (oneOf opChar) >> whiteSpace)


term = parens relexpr
       <|> Var <$> word
       <?> "term"

table = [ [postfix "^" Conv]
        , [binary ";" Comp AssocLeft]
        ]

prefix  name fun = Prefix  $ reservedOp2 name >> return fun
binary  name fun = Infix   $ reservedOp2 name >> return fun
postfix name fun = Postfix $ reservedOp2 name >> return fun

relexpr :: Parser RT
relexpr = buildExpressionParser table term <?> "expression"
```

Comment: Is your definition of `term` correct? Shouldn't it look like `parens  relexpr <|> ... Var word ... <?> "term"`? (comment about `binary` and assoc deleted)

Comment: @user5402 I think term is correctly defined, the problem is within the reservedOp2. This is the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

It fails to parse e.g. `"R^;S"` because `postfix "^" Conv` fails on `notFollowedBy (oneOf opChar)` (since `'^'` *is* followed by `';'`). The fix is to remove `';'` from `opChar`:

```
opChar = "^"
```

Or, even easier if you can just use `reservedOp` from `haskell`:

```
reservedOp2 = P.reservedOp haskell
```

Either of these changes fixes the parsing of your examples.